# JS square from 1 - 10

Tags: javascript

Hi I need to add to the table square fr 1 to 10 and I don't know what's wrong with my code (I'm new to JS)

Thanks for help

```
var kwad =[];

a = 1;


for (a>0; 10 === a; a++){
 kwad[a] = Math.pow(a,2) ;
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript for loop, each iteration will happen as long as second condition evaluates to `true`. In your case that never happens, because `10 === a` always equals false (because `a` equals 1, so `1 === 10` will give you false). You should fix your code in following way:

```
const kwad =[];


for (let a = 0; a < 10; a++){
 kwad[a] = Math.pow(a,2) ;
}
```

Ps. Besides all, first statement in for loop is initialization, so code `a > 0` doesn't really makes sense.